# Улучшение производительности интерактивного SVG на html странице

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

Всем привет! Имеется проблема с большим SVG. На странице необходимо отобразить SVG, но в нем порядка 20к элементов, весит под 20 мб. Сам SVG - это схема трубопроводов: 10 труб по 1500 метров каждая. Одна линия (path) - 1 метр трубы. Получается 15000 линий. id Каждой линии имеется в базе. База каждый день меняется, меняется именно параметр линии. В зависимости от параметра меняется цвет линии (красный, зеленый и т.д.). Трубы длинные, поэтому нужен зум, чтобы был виден текст(участок - 0, 1 метр и т.д. под каждой линией) и можно было перемещаться по этому SVG, используется svg-pan-zoom. Если бы элементов было не так много, то все шустро работало. Но чем их больше, тем медленнее работает. Весь код SVG вставлен в html как dom, то есть понимаете, как много строчек в html файле. Есть ли путь решения, как повысить скорость работы? Когда пытаешь зумить или перемещаться по свг - очень подтормаживает.Вот как выглядит (разумеется, вырезанная часть):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так примерно будут подкрашиваться все элементы по клику
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может рендерить тайлами на сервере? Как географические карты

Comment: Интерактивность не пропадет?

Comment: У вас слово "интерактивность" только в заголовке ;) Или вы pan/zoom имеете в виду?

Comment: Я же написал, что в зависимости от параметра меняется цвет линии (красный, зеленый и т.д.). Кликнул по кнопке и участки подкрасилии

Comment: Я читать умею. Вы пишите: *База каждый день меняется, меняется именно параметр линии. В зависимости от параметра меняется цвет линии (красный, зеленый и т.д.)*. Отсюда делаем однозначное умозаключение: цвет линии меняется каждый день. При чем здесь клик по кнопке? Об этом вы забыли написать. Ну и коль нужно нажимать на какую-то кнопку, опишите это подробнее, сколько кнопок, где они располагаются, вся труба просвечивается или участок? Вижу там ещё какие-то данные появились на втором скрине.

Comment: Кнопка одна - нажал и подсветилось. Подсвечивается все, в данном примере 15000 path элементов. А те данные со второго скрина - другая история. С первым бы разобраться. В данный момент решил использовать threejs библиотеку. Производительность поднялась, но фризы еще есть